# WebView transparent background in lower API level?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I use **webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);** in my program to make the webview with no background.

When I test it in my phone , which is 4.1.2 , it is ok with no error occur, however, when I tried to run it on emulator which is 2.3.7, the webview is corrupt, the background is black instead of transparent.

So , I google for the solution and found the layer = software, but when I add to it , the 4.1.2 one 's webview is corrupt , nothing is show.

I wonder how to fix it? Thanks for helping

Comment: Hey, did you resolved this problem?

Comment: no, too buggy, just use white background instead